# How to erase all the settings from Sublime Text after uninstalling?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I want to uninstall Sublime Text completely so I can reinstall it and reconfigure some settings. After I uninstall and reinstall a fresh new version. The previous settings and bugs (An extension errors keeps popping up) keep coming up. How and where do I go to you erase those settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's OS-dependent. What's probably happening is not all of your files are getting erased when you uninstall. You will need to manually delete these files. First, completely uninstall. Then manually delete the data folder. The location of the folder is OS and version (ST2 or ST3) dependent:

If you are on a Mac using ST2:
`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/`

If you are on a Mac using ST3:
`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/`

If you are on a PC using ST2:
`<username>/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 2/`

If you are on a PC using ST3:
`<username>/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/`

If you are on Linux using ST2:
`~/.config/sublime-text-2`

If you are on Linux using ST3:
`~/.config/sublime-text-3`
(thanks @MattDMo for Linux ST3 info)

**Source:** https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: you are correct about Linux, it's `~/.config/sublime-text-3`.